# why can't it display xlsx data, when selecting "Load File" a messagebox appears "The file you have chosen is invalid"

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

```
def File_dialog():
    """This Function will open the file explorer and assign the chosen file path to label_file"""
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                          title="Select A File",
                                          filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),("All Files", "*.*")))
    label_file["text"] = filename
    return None


def Load_excel_data():
    """If the file selected is valid this will load the file into the Treeview"""
    file_path = label_file["text"]
    try:
        excel_filename = r"{}".format(file_path)
        if excel_filename[-4:] == ".csv":
            df = pd.read_csv(excel_filename)
        else:
            df = pd.read_excel(excel_filename)

    except ValueError:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
        return None
    except FileNotFoundError:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
        return None

    clear_data()
    tv1["column"] = list(df.columns)
    tv1["show"] = "headings"
    for column in tv1["columns"]:
        tv1.heading(column, text=column)

    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        tv1.insert("", "end", values=row)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Wahidah, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read [ask] and structure the question a bit, and keep it short.

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  Have you verified that you're using the correct function to read? Have you examined the error message when you catch an error? Perhaps it is telling you something useful.

Comment: the xlsx file that you want to display cannot be displayed, and a notification appears "The file you have chosen is invalid"

Comment: You better print out the exception like: `except ValueError as ex:` and then `print(ex)`, so that you can know what exactly the error is.